# Tela branca ao logar em php

Tags: php

quando eu logo a tela fica em branco, alguém sabe que tipo de problema é esse?

página do login: https://pastebin.com/NtmYn2Pw

Pagina logar https://pastebin.com/XN1xEBMp

Alguém tem ideia qual o problema?

Comment: poste seu código aqui

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você não está passando o valor `"Logar"` no `$_POST['logar']`.

Teste o *POST* que está sendo enviado no arquivo `logar.php`utilizando `var_dump($_POST)` e confira o valor que está sendo passado.

Talvez não esteja entrando nesse `if`:

```
if (@$_POST['logar'] == 'Logar') { ... }
```

Já que seu `input[type="submit"]` está passando `"Sign Up"`:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-login" name="logar" id="logar" value="Sign Up" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu testando funcionou com o nome "Enviar" dessa forma

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-login" name="Enviar" value="Enviar" />
```

mas preciso que seja com **Sign Up**, tem ideia do que está errado ?